# Poping a base view . Will it pop all its child view?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a pushed a view(say for eg: first_view) using navigation controller, From that view I have pushed some other views,
In one situation an event will notify first view to pop, In such condition If I pop the view directly Will it pop all its child views properly by releasing its memories? Or Do I need to notify all child views to pop correspondingly.

Hope my question is understandable :)

Comment: what you want exactly ? and you want to go first parentview controller??

Comment: Notification will comes directly to Parent view only, How to pop all its child view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have pushed `viewController1, viewController2, viewController3`and`viewController4` in a `UINavigationController` and you call `[self.navigationController popToViewController:viewController1];` or `[self.navigationController popToRootViewController];` this will automatically pop `viewController2` and `viewController3` from navigation stack. You don't need to pop them explicitly.

Comment: Oh.. that one only I want to hear thanks. I will accept your answer after a while, so that we can get different opinion if any, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can back to ParentView with two way For ex.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

or

if you have `view1` after push in `view2` and then `view3` then if you want to pop to view2 then you can set with index of 1 and for `view1` index of 0

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];// set index of viewControler which you want to display
```

Comment: Yeah, I can pop parent view like that, what about it child views(Views pushed from parent) Do I need to pop all that first and then parent?

Comment: you want to automatically with animation it pop from child to parent??

Comment: hey you can also with index define this like this.. [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];// set index of viewControler which you want to display

Comment: No need. Popping only parent with animation is fine.

Comment: popToViewController: I have to do it in child view to go to parent, right? But I have instance of parent, Just I can pop it directly, What I want is all its child pushed though parent will be freed or not?

Comment: no but you can access this parent view from another view dude

Comment: I have a thread, that will intimate to parent view when its operation is done, now I need to pop all it child, So I am popping parent from parent only, so single popviewcontroller is fine right?